# При использовании Windows L&F в Swing не отображаются надписи у jTree

Tags: java, swing

Вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только при щелчке по какому-нибудь листу или узлу у него появляется надпись. Если убрать L&F и не использовать никакой совсем то надписи есть сразу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но хочется использовать L&F. Можно как это это исправить в Windows L&F?

Comment: Вы уверены, что он установлен? Мало ли, всякое бывает. Получить список доступных можно чем-то вроде import javax.swing.UIManager; public class MainClass { public static void main(String[] a) { UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] looks = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels(); for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo look : looks) { System.out.println(look.getClassName()); } } }

Comment: @hinotf, установлен, внешний вид то меняется